# Capacitor RC Charging

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, capacitor, current, resistors

I received this question as a homework:

"In an RC network with DC source, two capacitors added in parallel will reach a steady state voltage sooner than added same capacitors in series, considering all parameters unchanged. Caps have initial voltages zero. TRUE or FALSE"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUkGwX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please ignore the values of the Voltages, Capacitors and Resistors in the above two schematics. This is just a reference to show my understanding of the above question. I need to know which schematic would attain a steady state voltage at the respective nodes soon and why?

I have never read about series RC network. Even if that is the case, from where is the output voltage taken?

I do not understand. Can someone help me with a diagram to understand the difference and help me with the answer, please.

Comment: For this example, tapping the voltage across the resistor or the capacitor for determining steady state, either is okay. Convert the two capacitors to a single one using formula for series or parallel capacitor connection. This should give you an equivalent circuit for each example.

Comment: Please draw a diagram for each example as you have understood the question. Use the inbuilt circuit diagram editor. RC series circuit can be interpreted as a single loop with one voltage source, one resistor, and the equivalent capacitor in series.

Comment: @AJN, I have edited the question and added the schematic of what I have understood.

Comment: Now, you can replace the two capacitors in each circuit with an equivalent single capacitor. \$C1+C2\$ for one and \$\frac{C1C2}{C1+C2}\$. Then the circuit reduces to the simplest configuration of RC circuit. Use the equation for the voltage (or current) for that and see the result. The result will be of the form \$e^{-t/(R\cdot C_{equivalent})}\$ or similar. Plot the result to see the steady state from the result.

Comment: This is basic. Maybe you can write your own answer following AJN's comments.

Comment: @MituRaj, I wrote my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is FALSE.

Since, parallel capacitors increase the equivalent capacitance, this circuit will take more time to attain a steady state value when compared to the other schematic which has series capacitors.

Comment: Newbie, Great! Now try (really) to explain the answer yourself in a more intuitive way. This will give you more self-confidence.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist, yes ok thank you